# git "ping": check if remote repository exists

Tags: git

I'd like to know whether a remote repository exists.  Here's what I came up with:

```
git ls-remote -h "$REPO_URL" &> /dev/null
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: It seems like a fine choice. The overhead of the “extra work” of fetching and formatting the list of refs (which is then sent to `/dev/null`) should be fairly small.

Comment: The answer should be: No, there is no better way.

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: Check if git remote exists before first push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12170459/4561887)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I think the [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) command is pretty much made for that purpose.

Comment: yep, this seems to work, but can you, please, provide some explanation and tell if this 100% that I can clone that repo

Comment: If the server is *not* available, this is **slooooow** to respond. It takes 2.5 minutes or so. How can we speed this up? Here is my follow-up question: [Fast way to check if a git server is available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73297514/4561887)

Comment: git ping might be a nice alias for this

Answer (score 23):

If you use `--exit-code` argument you can skip sending output to `null`. It will return something only in case of error.

Also, you can use `-h` argument to show only heads references.

```
git ls-remote --exit-code -h "$REPO_URL"
```

Comment: `-h` is a great idea. However, `--exit-code` is not the right choice here. The man page says: *Exit with status "2" when no matching refs are found in the remote repository.* This means that `git ls-remote --exit-code "$REPO_URL"` will fail for an empty repo that has only just been initialized with `git init`.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

`git ls-remote` is the way, here is a shell-ready function for quick access:

```
  ## Returns errlvl 0 if $1 is a reachable git remote url 
  git-remote-url-reachable() {
      git ls-remote "$1" CHECK_GIT_REMOTE_URL_REACHABILITY >/dev/null 2>&1
  }
```

**Usage:**

```
if git-remote-url-reachable "$url"; then
   ## code
fi
```

**What is it doing ?**

This is just a convenient mash-up of all the comments/solutions previously stated with some small tweaks, a bash copy-paste ready function and usage code sample to make it crystal clear. You'll note that:

- it limits output as the reference checked (here `CHECK_GIT_REMOTE_URL_REACHABILITY`) is probably nonexistent on the remote server, and `git` doesn't have anything to answer back. We rely on the fact that `git`
  **will still exit with error-level 0 on non-existing ref**. The only difference
  here is that there are slightly less output to transfer on the network compared
  to ask for `HEAD` (and much less than not asking for a ref or even limiting to
  only heads), and this is also less output to cast in `/dev/null` (but this
  last one is taking negligible time anyway)
- the name of the ref checked that was chosen (which is `CHECK_GIT_REMOTE_URL_REACHABILITY`) **makes it clear we are probing for existence**, this could help
  if you want to be polite with the administrators of the server you are probing
  and give them a chance to understand why they receive these probes if they
  monitor anything.

Comment: as long as you're using bash, this is syntax is a little cleaner: &>/dev/null

Comment: What does `CHECK_GIT_REMOTE_URL_REACHABILITY` mean? What is it defined as, and where does it come from? I can't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: @GabrielStaples This is the arbitrary reference name mentioned in the answer, in the two point of the section "What is it doing". I tried to edit my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You can narrow output by using something like `git ls-remote "$REPO_URL" HEAD`

Comment: It hangs forever.

Comment: @Timo, then you probably have either unresponsive server or your connection or broken git client. For example network port is filtered. Further investigations is kinda similar to what happens when your ping doesn't respond :) . For example you can try check if you get connection established via [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or [openssl s_client](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html) or [tracepath](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tracepath).

Comment: @Timo, it doesn't actually hang "forever". Rather, if the git server is up and available, it returns in _3 to 30 seconds_, and if the server is down or unavailable, it returns in about _2.5 minutes_.

Answer (score 2):

By disabling asking for **credentials**, then listing the remote **head** only:

```
export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
git ls-remote "${repo}" HEAD &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most-reliable way I've found in bash is this:

```bash
if timeout 30s git ls-remote --tags > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Note: it takes 2~4 sec to get to here.
    echo "git server IS available"
else
    # Note: it takes 30 seconds (as specified by `timeout`) to get to here.
    echo "git server is NOT available"
fi
```

Optionally increase the `timeout 30s` value to a larger number of seconds if your server is unable to respond under normal conditions within that amount of time.

For a full and detailed explanation, see my main answers here:

1. [Stack Overflow: Check if git remote exists before first push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298218/4561887)
2. [Stack Overflow: Fastest way to check if a git server is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297645/4561887).